# Display Text(HTML) Saved In Database using CkEditor

Tags: php, mysql, ckeditor, richtext

I have used **CKEDITOR** for saving some text in **mysql database**, it is saved in format like I have shown below

```
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-size: 14px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Buy 2 Buffet and Get 1 Free (Mon-Wed-Thu-Fri-Sat-Sun)&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;
    &amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-size: 14px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Lunch buffet-&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-size: 14px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;Rs.399&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;br /&amp;gt;
    Dinner Buffet-&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;span style=&amp;quot;font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 14px;&amp;quot;&amp;gt;Rs.499&amp;lt;/span&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/strong&amp;gt;&amp;lt;/p&amp;gt;
&amp;lt;p style=&amp;quot;margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal; line-height: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);&amp;quot;&amp;gt;
```

For Displaying it I have used php code like

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($main_row['meta_value']))
```

But it is showing output like

```
<p style="margin: 0px; padding: 0px; border: 0px; color: rgb(0, 0, 0); font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; font-size: 12px; font-style: normal; font-variant: normal; font-weight: normal; letter-spacing: normal;
line-height: normal; orphans: auto; text-align: start; text-indent: 0px; text-transform: none; white-space: normal; widows: auto; word-spacing: 0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">  
<span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Buy 2 Buffet and Get 1 Free (Mon-Wed-Thu-Fri-Sat-Sun)</span></span><br /> <span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;">Lunch buffet-</span></span><span style="font-size: 14px;"><span style="font-family: arial, helvetica, sans-serif;"><strong>Rs.399</strong><br /> Dinner Buffet-</span></span>
```

I want to display this data as text, please help me out.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just try to use

```
echo htmlspecialchars_decode($text);
```

And it will work .

Comment: What is the benefit of doing `htmlspecialchars_decode()` twice? Why is this necessary?

Answer (score 1):

try this:

`echo htmlspecialchars_decode($main_row['meta_value'])`

and let me know what is the result..

Comment: hey you have used

`echo htmlspecialchars_decode(stripslashes($main_row['meta_value']))`

Comment: and i have removed the `stripslashes` part...have you tried this..and in your question where you have mentioned this..

Comment: It is not working, although I have tried `echo htmlspecialchars_decode ( htmlspecialchars_decode ( stripslashes ( $main_row[' meta_value '] ) ) )`   and it works, I know this is logically incorrect but it worked...

Answer (score 0):

**Use `html_entity_decode` it should work!**

For example, assuming your text is stored in a variable called $text
 `$text = html_entity_decode($text);`